# How do you replace an array in an ngrx state?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I made an API call which returns an array of Book objects, which I'm trying to place into my state by replacing the current results array. I've tried creating a new state object, using Objects.assign to create a new results array, and a few other things, but it seems like I'm not updating the state or results array properly as my selectors are not updating. I know that my reducer is definitely being hit though, since I had some logging in there earlier.

Here is the state object:

```
export interface BooksState {
  books: Book[];
  results: Book[];
}
```

here is my current reducer:

```
const booksReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(BooksActions.SearchBookSuccess, (state, { payload }) => {
    const newState = {
      ...state,
      results: payload
    };
    return newState;
  })
);

export function reducer(state: BooksState | undefined, action: Action) {
  return booksReducer(state, action);
}
```

this is where I dispatch the action:

```
searchBooks$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(BookActions.SearchBookRequested),
      Rx.mergeMap(action =>
        this.bookService.search(action.payload).pipe(
          Rx.map(results =>
            BookActions.SearchBookSuccess({ payload: results })
          ),
          Rx.catchError(() => BookActions.SearchBookFailure)
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

and this is my selector:

```
this.results$ = store.select(getResults);
```

With the selector I have also tried creating a function `export const getResults = (state: BooksState) => state.results` and selecting that with `store.select` without any success either.

What am I missing?

Comment: If payload type is  `Book[]`, then the reducer looks fine to me. Add your selectors and your dispatch `SearchBookSuccess` action.

Comment: Added the selector and `SearchBookSuccess` action dispatch

Comment: If your initial state has `results=[]`, try to start with a non empty value and see the select result. Just to check if the selector is OK.

Comment: BTW are you using the devtools?

Comment: One last thing, In this case I would use `switchMap` instead of `mergeMap`, I think is better to cancel the previous subscription.

Comment: Looks like my selectors were messed up. I started having selectors start with the top level `AppState` and chaining them with `createSelector` and everything works. I was using chrome's built in devtools.